# How to split an array in equal chunks in C?

Tags: c, arrays, chunks

If I have an array with dynamic size, and not always a constant size, and want to split the array in 5 equal chunks. How is it possible to implement i C ?

The size of the array could for instance be:

```
int file[1000];
int file2[2000];
int file3[3000];
```

Thank you in advance.